# Testing Android app with Google Play Game Services on multiple machines

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I've created an app on Google Play Developer Console and generated a Client ID using the `debug.keystore`. On the same machine I can build to device and emulator and login without problems. However if I do the same from another computer I can't login becuase it doesn't have the same key.

I guess I can solve this by copying the `debug.keystore` from one computer to another but is there a better way to do this while testing the app?

Comment: yeah add the keys for each computer in your developer console

Comment: One way is to type in the keys as @tyczj suggests, i personally find it easier to copy around the debug.keystore file (or share it on the network).